# :Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, backup, azure-analysis-services

Hey I just started learning AAS and I am facing issue with backup
encountering this error while taking analysis service backup: Backup-ASDatabase :Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQrcc.png)

Solution for this error

Answer (score 0):

The **Backup-ASDatabase** command uses credentials from your PC to log in to Azure, and they don't match, resulting in an error. Use parameter **Credential**:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Backup-ASDatabase "mydb.abf" -Server "myserver" -Credential $cred
```